# Create Unique Path Within Each SVG Group Element Using D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create 50 SVG groups with each group containing a path that draws a particular US state. However, I can't figure out how to access the state data from the SVG group when creating the state path for that group. Can someone put me on the right track? Thanks!

```
var coords = [
    { 'id':'HI', 'class':'state hi', 'd': 'm 233.08751,519.30948 1.93993, ...' },
    { 'id':'AK', 'class':'state ak', 'd': 'm 158.07671,453.67502 -0.32332, ...'}
    ...
];

// Select the SVG
var svgContainer = d3.select('svg');

// Create groups with state data
var groups = svgContainer.selectAll('g')
    .data(coords)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

// Create state path for each group
groups.each(function(g){
    g.select('path')
        .data(___NEED TO RETURN THE PATH DATA HERE___)
        .enter()
        .append('path');
});
```

Uncaught TypeError: g.select is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is valid and you only want to handle new elements (no updates), this should work:

```
// Select the SVG
var svgContainer = d3.select('svg');

// Create groups with state data
var groups = svgContainer.selectAll('g')
    .data(coords)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function (d) { return d.d; });
```

I have created a pretty simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakcpysk/) with an example.

If you still want to use the `.each` function, you can proceed as follows:

```
groups.each(function (d, i){
    // `this` (in this context) is bound to the current DOM element in the enter selection
    d3.select(this).append('path').attr('d', d.d);
});
```

For further details, you can check the [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me why I was getting the "g.select is not a function" error? I've been reading about selections, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Glad could help :) `each` function accepts two arguments; the first one is the datum associated to the element and the second one the index within the current selection; that's why you get such error. I would recommend you this read about this topic: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/.